# How do i get variable name of jbutton here"s101"?

Tags: java, mysql, jbutton

**I want to get the value of my jbutton and compare it with my database column and set the text of the label**

```
private void s101ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                    

         try
        {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/abc","root","");
            PreparedStatement stm = con.prepareStatement("select * from seats where Seat_id="+s101.getName());
            ResultSet rs = stm.executeQuery(); 
            while(rs.next())
               // if(s101.getAccessibleContext().equals(rs.getString("Seat_id")))
                    {
                        lbl_id.setText(rs.getString("Seat_id"));
                        lbl_name.setText(rs.getString("Seat_name"));
                        lbl_price.setText(rs.getString("Price"));
                        lbl_type.setText(rs.getString("Type"));
                    }    
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: if(s101.getAccessibleContext().getAccessibleName().equals(rs.getString("Seat_id")))

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to get the text display on button and compare it with database value. To achieve that you should get source from action event.

```
JButton button = (JButton) evt.getSource();
String name = button.getText();
```

Then use name to compare with database.

```
name.equals(rs.getString("Seat_id")
```